# Как закрыть меню при клике вне него и при повторном клике на гамбургер?

Tags: jquery

При клике на кнопку открывается меню. При клике вне меню оно закрывается. При клике на кнопку-гамбургер меню также должно закрываться, если оно открыто. Но у меня получается повторное открытие меню, сразу после закрытия, и оно не закрывается. Как сделать закрытие при клике вне меню, а также при клике на кнопку, если меню открыто?

```
$(".menu_btn").click(function() {
        if (!$("header").hasClass("open_menu")) {
            $("header").addClass("open_menu");
        }
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        var $target = $(e.target);
        if ($target.closest("nav").length === 0) {
            $("header").removeClass("open_menu");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".menu_btn").click(function() {
            $(".header").toggleClass("open_menu");  
});

    $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        var $target = $(e.target);
        if ($target.closest(".nav").length == 0) {
            $(".header").removeClass("open_menu");
        }
    });
```

```css
.nav{

  width:250px;

}
.header{
display:none;
}

.open_menu{
display:block;
  border:2px solid red;
  background:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='nav'>
<button class='menu_btn'>Click me</button>
<ul class='header'>
<li>1111111111111111111111</li>
  <li>1111111111111111111111</li>
  <li>1111111111111111111111</li>
  <li>1111111111111111111111</li>
  <li>1111111111111111111111</li>
  <li>1111111111111111111111</li>
  <li>1111111111111111111111</li>
  <li>1111111111111111111111</li>
</ul>
  </div>
```

**UPD**

```js
$(".menu_btn").click(function() {
  $(".header").toggleClass("open_menu");
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var $target = $(e.target);
  if ($target.closest(".header").length == 0 && $target.closest(".menu_btn").length == 0) {
    $(".header").removeClass("open_menu");
  }
});
```

```css
.header {
  display: none;
}
.open_menu {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class='menu_btn'>Click me</button>
<ul class='header'>
  <li>1111111111111111111111</li>
  <li>1111111111111111111111</li>
  <li>1111111111111111111111</li>
  <li>1111111111111111111111</li>
  <li>1111111111111111111111</li>
  <li>1111111111111111111111</li>
  <li>1111111111111111111111</li>
  <li>1111111111111111111111</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Не подскажите, почему закрывается блок при клике слева/справа/снизу, но не сверху?

Comment: @ВикторПавлов где сверху?

Comment: http://joxi.ru/KAg7ZBOSg1ld5A

Comment: @ВикторПавлов потомучто, кнопка и открывающийся блок лежат в блоке ('nav');

Comment: @ВикторПавлов добавил update, чуть другой вариант...

Comment: @C.Raf.T здравствуйте! Мне очень помог ваш ответ, чтобы справиться со своим мобильным меню. Можно попросить вас, если не сложно, по шагам объяснить, что вы делаете в своем коде? Просто я в jquery почти ничего не понимаю, но не хочу просто бездумно копировать решения.

Comment: @Alla что именно вас интересует?

Comment: @C.Raf.T если это не сложно, то рассказать об используемых функциях и как их между собой стыковать или дать ссылку на ресурс,где можно прочесть. Просто то, что я находила, производило ощущение размазанной информации.

Comment: @Alla в рамках здешнего форума это не реально... но я бы вам советовал для понемания фунций и вообще для понемания jQuery, по большей части, обращаться к первоисточнику http://jquery.com/   там достаточно полно изложено описание и примеры.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```
$(".menu_btn").click(function() {
            if (!$("header").hasClass("open_menu")) {
                $("header").toggleClass("open_menu");
            }
        });

        $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
            var $target = $(e.target);
            if ($target.closest("nav").length === 0) {
                $("header").toggleClass("open_menu");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Работает точно также, как и у меня. Есои меню открыто и кликнуть на гамбургер, меню не закрывается.

Comment: Что за "гамбургер"?! Дайте HTML

Comment: Гамбургер - обычная кнопка.